# Android Override methods inside classes with Activity parameter

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, overriding

I want to know if I put my activity through other class like this way:

```
public class GateActivity extends MapActivity {

private Presenter assistant = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    assistant = new Presenter(this);
// ...
}
```

And this other class:

```
public class Presenter {
private android.app.Activity act;

public Presenter(android.app.Activity a){
    this.act = a;
    // ...
}
```

If it's possible in "Presenter" class to create an intent like this:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
act.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

AND create/handle its "Override onActivityResult(...)" method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (requestCode){
    case 1: // ...
}
```

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that should work.

When the called activity has completed, `GateActivity.onActivityResult()` will be called.

Comment: Hi David! But I want to know how can I handle the activity result **inside Presenter class**, because in my architecture the GateActivity class only passes the activity to the Presenter and doesn't do anymore.

Comment: You can't. Directly. You would have to have `GateActivity.onActivityResult()` delegate the call to `Presenter.onActivityResult()`

Comment: Sounds like your architecture is kinda broken. Why don't you just have `Presenter` inherit from `GateActivity`?

Comment: Hi David! The teacher of my final degree project established this architecture...
Thanks anyway! ;)